While opening file manager using SAF can I redirect directly to my selected folder instead of just opening the file manager?
While opening SAF, whatever directory path I have selected directly that should be open instead of just open file manager
I am using Kotlin and Android Studio.
Below code I am opening SAF
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
Log.e("check", "uri: " +getTargetUri(filePathToBeShare))
Log.e("check", "filePathToBeShare: " +filePathToBeShare)                         intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,getTargetUri(filePathToBeShare))
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE -> {
                    val status = exportFileToExternalStorage(processURIData(data!!))
                    if (status == EXPORT_SUCCESS) {

                        if (typeCopyOrMove.equals(getString(R.string.title_copy))){
                            showCustomToast(getString(R.string.file_copy))
                            TTSUtils.playTTSOnTouch(context, getString(R.string.file_copy))
                        }else if (typeCopyOrMove.equals(getString(R.string.title_move))){
                            showCustomToast(getString(R.string.file_move))
                            TTSUtils.playTTSOnTouch(context, getString(R.string.file_move))

                        }else{

                            showCustomToast(getString(R.string.toast_on_export))
                            //TTS
                            TTSUtils.playTTSOnTouch(context, getString(R.string.toast_on_export))
                            //mAdapter?.updateList(getListOfDirectory(pathToSearch)!!)
                            //IndicatorUtils.hideProgress(activity)
                        }

                        deleteFileIfMove()

//                        showCustomToast(getString(R.string.toast_on_export))
                        if (activity is GalleryActivity) {
                            (activity as GalleryActivity).popAllFragmentBack()
                        }
                        if (activity is FileManagerActivity) {
                            (activity as FileManagerActivity).popAllFragmentBack()
                        }
                    } else {
                        showCustomToast(getString(R.string.went_wrong))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


This question is similar to: How can I set the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE start path the first time a user uses my app?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I tried "DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI" but its not working in my case. I am passing the uri like "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/Test4". Is this correct or something missing?
